# I am getting the following error: Warning in install.packages

Tags: r, swirl

I am getting the following error when installing the swirl package in R.

```
install.packages('swirl')
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>      'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"' is not writable

It then asks whether you want to create  personal directory. When you say yes the response is the following:

> Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘//isad.isadroot.xx.ac.uk/UOX/User/R/win-library/3.3

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. Talk to your system admin.

Comment: Almost surely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run R program as an Administration: Right click R program icon and choose "Run as Administrator", if you see a User Account Control prompt, accept it.